# Change Migration Type from Date to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I change the migration from Date type to Integer?
I looked up in the official Rails website and they said I should write change_column.

I tried this:

```
def change
  change_column :books, :publish_year, :integer
end
```

but this gave me the error:

> PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "publish_year" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
>   HINT:  You might need to specify "USING publish_year::integer".
>   : ALTER TABLE "books" ALTER COLUMN "publish_year" TYPE integer

I want my books publish_year column to be the type integer and not date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `remove_column :books, :publish_year`
then do `add_column :books, :publish_year, :integer`.

You can do both in one migration but I'll usually do each method in a different migration, makes rolling back easier for me!

Comment: it gives me this error: PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type date to integer
LINE 1: ...s" ALTER COLUMN "publish_year" TYPE integer USING CAST(publi...
                                                             ^
: ALTER TABLE "books" ALTER COLUMN "publish_year" TYPE integer USING CAST(publish_year AS integer)

Comment: Do  you have important data in that column of the table?

Comment: not really, i am still in developing mode, so right now my seeds are all made by myself

Comment: ok thanks! but do you know the reason why it won't work with the change_column?

Comment: So PG is finding it hard to parse some dates to integers. The alternative is to write an 'IF-THEN-ELSE' condition  to handle those kind of dates, implying you'll have to write raw SQL which I'm guessing you're not an expect at.

Answer (score 4):

Try this bro,

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'integer USING CAST(column_name AS integer)'
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: It gives me this error: PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type date to integer
LINE 1: ...s" ALTER COLUMN "publish_year" TYPE integer USING CAST(publi...
                                                             ^
: ALTER TABLE "books" ALTER COLUMN "publish_year" TYPE integer USING CAST(publish_year AS integer)

Answer (score 1):

The Main reason would be PgSQL public API and methods they allow depending upon the version.

There is no such operation in PostgreSQL say [version 7.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/ddl-alter.html) to update the column data type. If you read the operation list, you can see in the link the operations allowed.

Now, in later PgSQL such as [version 9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-alter.html), they added that operation.

They added it in version 8.0

So depending upon the version of PgSQL, you may get the error or it may work. I will suggest you update your PgSQL and if you are using a third party database, ask them to update that.

But for earlier cases you can just use the way of deleting and creating tables or columns through migrations to achieve the results.

Hope that explains!

Comment: I see, I it kinda said once that I should update my PgSQL. I'll do this then!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def change
  execute <<-SQL
    ALTER TABLE detail_analyses
    ALTER COLUMN reporting_year TYPE integer USING EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 
                 reporting_year)::integer,
    ALTER COLUMN reporting_month TYPE integer USING EXTRACT(MONTH FROM 
                 reporting_month)::integer
  SQL
end
```